# Prevent the reset of app in simulator/real device iOS appium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

```
//Already set the noReset flag to true in Desired capabilities
@Test
public void testSomeThing()
{
  syso("Do something")
}

@AfterMethod
public void closeApp()
{
  driver.closeApp();
}

@Test    
public void WantToOpenAppWithoutResetinIos()
{
  driver.launchApp();

  //carry on with testing
}
```

But the problem is that the simulator is getting reset after each test; any pointers on solving the issue? I don't want to reset the iOS simulator after each state, I want to use the data entered in test1 to be used for test2.

Comment: need more info, especially about version of software you are using and your testing environment.

Comment: @YuZhang :appium java client 3.0.0; appium version 1.4.0; simulator 5s 8.4 ; Let me know if you know any more information

Answer (score 0):

You are using annotation @AfterMethod which runs after each test. Instead use @AfterClass and execute it again.

Comment: intentiontially i have put @AfterMethod because i want to launch the app after each test case not on completing the test suite

Comment: ok..try @AfterClass and use launch() method wherever you want to launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following capability in your `launchApp()`:

```
capabilities.setCapability("noReset", true);
```